# lesson_location Element in SCORM 1.2 data model

Tags: scorm1.2

There is a lesson_location Element in the data model used to store the position where the student left off in the SCO.

Is there any element which decribes the total number of slides or total number of lessons that can be bookmarked in the scorm package in SCORM 1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not officially. Courses can be built in any fashion, there is no expectation that there will be a slide number.

Most people use `suspend_data` to store a custom string containing the info you require. You could also store it in `lesson_location`.

For example (and this is just one of many ways to do it):

```
var totalSlides = 10;
var currentSlide = 3;
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", currentSlide + "|" + totalSlides);
var lmsdata = LMSGetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location").split("|");
totalSlides = lmsdata[1];
currentSlide = lmsdata[0];
```

This is a very contrived example, but you get the point. Don't forget to add error checking, this example will throw an error if there is no second element in the `lmsdata` array. You could also use JSON, but it's more verbose and eats up characters -- `lesson_location` and `suspend_data` have limitations to the number of characters that can be stored, esp. in SCORM 1.2.

See all the data model elements here: http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/